# How can I create NSLayoutConstraint object that is exactly same as @"H:|-10-[view]" in code?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've been trying to figure out how to create an `NSLayoutConstraint` object using `NSLayoutConstraint`'s constraintWithItem method that is equivalent to code below.

```
NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:"@H:|-10-[view]"
                                                               options:0
                                                               metrics:nil
                                                                 views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(view)];

NSLayoutConstraint *rightMarginConstraint = [constraints firstObject];
```

I've tried codes like below:

```
NSLayoutConstraint* rightMarginConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:superview
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                    multiplier:1.0f
                                                      constant:10.0f];
```

but it doesn't do quite same thing, and it's different on the console when it printed out. I want a constraint that is printed out as `"H:|-10-[view]"` on console.

Does anyone know how to create one that works both iOS7 and 8? (I found there are new attribute options for iOS 8, but I still support iOS 7)

Thanks in advance!

///////// Edit ////////

Actually the 2nd block of code produced exactly same constraint on simple view & superview.
However, I'm having issue on TableViewCells and I'm getting result below:

This is what I want and produced with the code similar to the first block of code

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc050f481c0 H:|-(10)-[UIView:0x7fc050f48070]   (Names: 　　　　'|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fc050f39310 )>
```

The second block of code produces constraint similar to output below

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b6513d0 view:0x7b64cdf0.leading == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b64cd10.left>
```

///Edit 2///
I'm also getting output looks like code below even I used matched attributes.

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d695c70 CustomBorderView:0x7d4cb0f0.right == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7d4cb010.right + 10>
```

///Edit 3///

I figured the order of the item matters. I swapped argument for constraintWithItem: and toItem: and now outputs what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: What does it do, and what does it print out to the console?

Comment: Show us the printed logs of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSLayoutAttributeLeft` is not the same as `NSLayoutAttributeLeading`.  Try this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint* rightMarginConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
     multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
```

or this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint* rightMarginConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
    constraintWithItem:view  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
    toItem:superview attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
     multiplier:1.0f constant:10.0f];
```

Both of these give me your desired output.  Mixing `...Left` and `...Leading` gives me your unwanted output.

Comment: I've tried both and they give me the same result. For me Left should have been absolute, and leading should be relative, but I can't really make out the difference bw both of them. Can someone explain when and how to use Leading and Left differently?